# Stationary processes and their power

Tags: fourier-transform, power-spectral-density

The top answer to this question: [Power spectral density vs Energy spectral density](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10148/power-spectral-density-vs-energy-spectral-density) states:

> However if random process is stationary, then it is for sure that it
>   has some finite power over some band of frequencies

Why is that? Also, is stationarity a necessary condition for a process to have finite power over a band of frequencies?

Comment: The highlighted statement above is false.  Read [this answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/488/235).