# How to show that an ergodic process must be a strict-sense stationary one?

Tags: ergodic, stationary

I have trouble to distinguish these two concepts namely ergodic process and strict-sense stationary process. I look at one of the books about the signal processing that says an ergodic process must be a strict-sense stationary one. So how to show this property?

Can anyone help??

Thanks,
Victor

Comment: What is your understanding of the meaning of ergodicity?  Also, this question is closely related to [What is the distinction between ergodic and stationary](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/1167/235) and reading the answers there might help.

Comment: I am quite new to this topic, and I think what you said makes senses for me to distinguish both concepts. But I still cannot observe or understand what is the relationship between these two. I think what you meant in the previous post implies erogic process => stationary, while stationary process is not sufficient to guarantee ergodicity, right?

Comment: You _still_ need to tell us what _you_ understand by ergodicity. A few words will suffice; no need for a formal mathematical definition.

Comment: I think it should be something like this: The statistics properties can be determined from a long sampled process? Another type of understanding for this, if I understand is correct, no matter where the position for the initial point locates, the system will still reach the steady state or converge in a dynamical system.