# explanation of correlation of stationary stochastic processes

Tags: correlation, stochastic, random-process

I have some doubts about correlation in `stationary stochastic processes`.

I know that the expectation of a random variable is 
$$E(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} a f_x(a)da$$
and the `mutual correlation` of two variables is $E(x_1 x_2)$.

In two stationary stochastic processes the mutual correlation should be $E(x_1(t+\tau)x_2(t))$ now when and why I can translate this formula in:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x_1(t+\tau)x_2(\tau)d\tau
$$
I have not understand where this last formula comes from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing up two different notions.

Your random process is a *collection* of random variables $\{X(t)\colon -\infty < t < \infty\}$, one random variable for each time instant. The autocorrelation function of the process is
$$R_X(t, \hat{t}) = E[X(t)X(\hat{t})], -\infty < t, \hat{t} < \infty$$
and is a *two-dimensional* function (meaning it has two arguments,
and if you try to visualize it, you should imagine a *surface* above 
(and possibly
below) the plane with coordinate axes $t$ and $\hat{t}$. Definitely above
because $R_X(t,t) = E[(X(t))^2]\geq 0$ for all $t$ (and processes for
which $R_X(t,t) = 0$ for all $t$ are kinda boring).

For a *stationary* process, $R(t,\hat{t})$ depends only on the
*difference* $\hat{t}-t$ of the two arguments, and it is common
practice to write it as a function of one variable $\tau = \hat{t}-t$.
Thus,
$$\mathcal R(\tau) = R(t,\hat{t}) = E[X(t)X(t+\tau)].$$

The *other* notion is that if the experiment is performed, then
each random variable takes on a numerical value. Thus, $X(t)$ takes
on a specific numerical value that we name as $x(t)$ while
$X(\hat{t})$ takes on some other numerical value that we name
as $x(\hat{t})$ and so on. Thus, we have a *real-valued* function
(or signal) $x(t)$ (nothing random about that!) for which the
autocorrelation function is defined as
$$R_x(\tau) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t)x(t+\tau)\,\mathrm dt.$$
Note that $x(t)$ is called a *sample path* or *realization*
of the random process: it is what you observe on your oscilloscope
if you lift up your head from the math a little bit
and look at the real world.

It is every DSPer's fondest hope that $R_x(\tau)$ is the same function
as $\mathcal R(\tau)$. Unfortunately, *nothing* in what has been
said above justifies this hope. But, since people like to assume
that it is indeed true that $R_x(\tau) = \mathcal R_X(\tau)$, mathematicians have come
up with a notion called *ergodicity* which (for our purposes) says that
for an *ergodic* process, the *ensemble* means (expectations)
equal the corresponding time-averages.  As a *practical* matter,
all model-builders *assume* that the processes that they want
to model are indeed both stationary and ergodic,
and decide on what the mean and
the autocorrelation function etc should be by making observations of
actual sample paths etc.

For more than what you probably want to know about random processes,
see [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/488/235) of mine, and
for an example of a (boring) stationary random process that is 
*not* ergodic, see [this other answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/1169/235) of mine.

Comment: Thanks, you have really clarified my ideas.
I would like to ask you in practice what do I need autocorrelation? I used mutual correlation to compare two signals, but what about autocorrelation?

Comment: The mutual correlation (usually called the _cross-correlation_) does indeed tell you the similarity between two signals. Computing $\int x(t)y(t+\tau) dt$ for various values of $\tau$ tells you for _which_ relative delays between $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ the two signals are most similar, but the differences between `most similar` and `least similar` are relatively small. When $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are the _same_ signal with _different_ delays, there is a very _pronounced_ peak in the cross-correlation function at the value of $\tau$ which aligns the two signals perfectly. (continued)

Comment: (continuation) In fact, this peak is used for estimating the delay between a _radar return_ (weak, noisy reflection from a target of the transmitted signal) and the transmitted signal itself. Why the value of this delay might be of any interest to a radar engineer or the engineer's bosses or customers is something I will leave to you to decide.

Comment: Yes, I know that the _cross-correlation_ is often used to find the $\tau$ of the noise in the signal, but I wanted to ask which information can I get from the `autocorrelation` of the realization of a random process.

Comment: The autocorrelation function of the realization is a _model_ for (or _estimate_ of) the autocorrelation function of the random process. The information that you get from the model or estimate is the mean and variance of each  of the random variables $X(t)$ (same for all the random variables) as well as the correlation between each _pair_ of random variables $X(t)$ and $X(t+\tau)$. For _Gaussian_ processes, this is sufficient information to write down the joint density of _any_ $n$ random variables in the process. See my _other_ answer that I referred you to for details.