# Difference between cross correlation definitions (signal processing / random processes)

Tags: cross-correlation

I'm trying to understand the similarities/differences between the following definitions for cross correlation)

Signal Processing: (or it's discrete equivalent)
$$R_{XY}(\tau) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^*(t) y(t+ \tau) dt$$

Random Processeses$$R_{XY}(t_1, t_2) = E\begin{Bmatrix}
X_{t_1} Y^*_{t_2}
\end{Bmatrix}$$

Are these related?

Comment: Yes, but one is deterministic and the other is probabilistic. They both are measures of similarity.

Comment: See [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/27139/235) for some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

If the process is stationary it is ergodic, then time averages are equal to probabilistic averages.