# Ergodicity clarification

Tags: discrete-signals, digital-communications, stochastic, ergodic

On page 201 of [https://stanford.edu/~dntse/Chapters_PDF/Fundamentals_Wireless_Communication_chapter5.pdf](https://stanford.edu/%7Edntse/Chapters_PDF/Fundamentals_Wireless_Communication_chapter5.pdf),
it is mentioned that

> This observation suggests that the capacity result (5.89) holds for a much
> broader class of fading processes. Only the convergence in (5.91) is needed.
> This says that the time average should converge to the same limit for almost all
> realizations of the fading process, a concept called ergodicity, and it holds in
> many models.

I just wanted to confirm if my interpretation of this is correct: in equation (5.91), the $h[m]$ are **random variables** taken from a **discrete random process** $h$. This leads to another discrete random process $\log(1+ |h|^2 SNR)$ and assuming it is ergodic in the mean, equation 5.91 holds.

Comment: It seems to me that, ***directly from*** the meaning of *"ergodic"* (in every sense), that Eq. 5.91 holds.  That's the meaning of *ergodicity*.  If it's generally *ergodic*, that means that every time average of ***any*** continuous function of $h[n]$ must be equal to the probabilistic average of the same function of $h[n]$ (i.e. the Expected Value of that same function of $h[n]$).  I do not know why they say: *"By the law of large numbers, ..."*  It's because it's **ergodic**.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/1169/235) to be useful, or, perhaps adding to your confusion!

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson "By the law of large numbers" is sufficient to have the converge, which is *also* the consequence of ergodicity assumption embedded in chosen models. Just being rigorous I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll change the notation a little.  Let's say you have a discrete-time process, $x[n]$, random or deterministic, that exists for all discrete times $n$, and let's say it goes into some *"decent"* (I think *continuous*) function $f(x)$.

The time-average of the result of that function is:

$$ \overline{f(x)} \triangleq \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{2N+1} \sum\limits_{n=-N}^{+N} f\big( x[n] \big) $$

Now, let's say that $x[n]$ is a stationary random process, so all statistics of $x[n]$ are constant with respect to (discrete) time $n$.  Then the probabilistic-average of the result of that function is the expectation value:

$$ \mathbb{E}\Big\{ f\big( x[n] \big)\Big\} \triangleq \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathrm{p}_x(\alpha) f\big( \alpha \big)  \  \mathrm{d}\alpha $$

where $\mathrm{p}_x(\alpha)$ is the probability density function (p.d.f.) of the random variable $x[n]$ and is independent of $n$:

$$ \int\limits_{\alpha}^{\alpha + \Delta \alpha} \mathrm{p}_x(u) \ \mathrm{d}u = \mathbb{P}\Big\{\alpha \le x[n] < \alpha + \Delta \alpha \Big\}  $$

or, for tiny $\Delta \alpha$,

$$ \mathrm{p}_x(\alpha) = \lim_{\Delta \alpha \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta \alpha} \mathbb{P}\Big\{\alpha \le x[n] < \alpha + \Delta \alpha \Big\} $$

and $\mathbb{P}\big\{\cdot\big\}$ means *the probability of the event defined therein*.

Now, my understanding of the root meaning to the term ***ergodic*** as applied to a random process $x[n]$, is that every time average is the same as the probabilistic average.  That is, for any function $f(\cdot)$,

$$ \overline{f(x)} = \mathbb{E}\Big\{ f\big( x[n] \big)\Big\} $$

That's what *"ergodic"* means.  These are two different ways of getting to the average of something, and *"ergodic"* means that those two different ways of getting to the average, get to the ***same*** average.

Comment: So in my case, I have the discrete time process $x[n] = h$ and $f(x) = log(1 + |x|^2 SNR)$ correct?

Comment: Yup,...........